# previous / next post with thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I've got another question regarding next / previous post.

At the moment I'm working on our portfolio with several items. Each item is a post with a title, category & featured image. When viewing an item there are 4 next/previous posts.

How do I display the next 2 and previous 2? And If the next or previous don't exist how do I show only 4 previous or 4 next posts (at the first and last post)?

Currently I'm using twitter bootstrap CSS/HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid tab-footer">

        <div class="span3">



                      <div class="row-fluid none">
                           <div class="span3">THUMBNAIL</div>

                           <div class="span9" ><h2>TITLE</h2>

                           <p><?php
                                foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
                                if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) {
                                echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">';
                                 echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a> ';
                                }}
                                ?>
                            </p> 
                      </div>

        </div> 

        <div class="span3 hidden-phone">

                  <div class="row-fluid none">
                       <div class="span3">THUMBNAIL</div>

                       <div class="span9" ><h2>TITLE</h2>

                       <p>CATEGORY</p> 
                  </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 hidden-phone">
                  <div class="row-fluid none">
                       <div class="span3">THUMBNAIL</div>

                       <div class="span9" ><h2>TITLE</h2>

                       <p>CATEGORY</p> 
                  </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3">   
                  <div class="row-fluid none">
                       <div class="span3">THUMBNAIL</div>

                       <div class="span9" ><h2>TITLE</h2>

                       <p>CATEGORY</p> 
                  </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a custom query to get a list of posts. In this example we use a custom post type "project" and a custom taxonomy "sphere" and we get 1 next project in current sphere. In your use case you can increase posts_per_page to 4.

```
<?php 
//remember the id and menu_order from current post 
$id=get_the_ID(); 
global $haet_post_order; 
$haet_post_order=$post->menu_order;

//There is only one sphere per project in this example
$custom_terms = get_the_terms($id, 'sphere');
foreach ($custom_terms AS $term) {
    $sphere=$term->slug;
}

function haet_filter_next_post( $where = '' ) {
    global $haet_post_order;
    $where .= ' AND menu_order>'.$haet_post_order;
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'haet_filter_next_post' );
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby' => 'menu_order','order' => 'ASC','sphere'=>$sphere ) );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'haet_filter_next_post' );

//if there is no next post use the first one
if( !$loop->have_posts() ){
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby' => 'menu_order','order' => 'ASC','sphere'=>$sphere ) );
}

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// place you code here
?>

<?php  endwhile;  ?>
```

Inside the while loop you can get the thumbnail with [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail). You can find a few more lines of description in [this blog post](http://haet.at/get-custom-post-custom-taxonomy-wordpress/)

Comment: Super Hannes, great answer!