# WordPress "Next Post" URL and Thumbnail

Tags: next-post-link

I am a noobie. Building my new theme. I just need to get 3 separate data:

- $image = direct link to the next post thumb image (just the link)
- $name = Next post name
- $url = Next post URL

Looked at [previous / next post with thumbnail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106676/previous-next-post-with-thumbnail) dosnt work for me....

Thank you for any help)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`get_adjacent_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) function for retrieving that data. This function retrieve adjacent post. Can either be next or previous post.

**For previous post**

```
<?php

  $prevpost = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true, 'category' );

  $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $prevpost );
  $name = get_the_title( $prevpost );
  $url = get_permalink( $prevpost );

?>
```

**For next post**

```
<?php

  $nextpost = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false, 'category' );

  $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $nextpost );
  $name = get_the_title( $nextpost );
  $url = get_permalink( $nextpost );

?>
```

Comment: I would cache it in a variable `$next_post = ...`, otherwise it's a little expensive to call it repeatedly.

Comment: Originally I did but when I tested it didn't work with the variable. So had to change it. But that could be me only :) Anyway changed it again.

Comment: Also wrap `$nextpost`/`$prevpost` in an `if` - if there is no next/previous post, the following `get_*` functions will return data for the current post.